# Command line interpretor

Tags: c, unix

The task  is to create a simple command line interpretor. It should say a prompt like '$>' showing that it is prepared to accept a user command. It has to execute user commands, from the list of accepted commands.

```
1. The "nl" command. Parameters that need to be implemented are: -s, -d

2. The "mv" command. Parameters that need to be implemented are: -i, -t -s

3. The "cd" command. No parameters need to be implemented.
```

> The nl command -s, --number-separator=string
>   Separates the line number from the text line in the output with string (default is a TAB character).
>
> Command nl-d, --section-delimiter=cc Sets the two delimiter characters that indicate the beginnings of logical page sections; if only one is given, the second remains ':'. To enter '\', use '\'.
>   The mv renames a file or moves it from one directory to another directory.
>
> Command mv-i prompts before overwriting another file and for the other two I couldn't find any specifications whatsoever.
>   The cd command is used to get back to home directory.

So fart that is all I know. It has to be written in C but be appropriate for UNIX. I have not started anything and I would appreciate any help and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Advice: open up a text editor. Start writing code. Compile, test. Ask if you have a specific problem.

Comment: This is way too broad a question for this site, you need to ask very specific questions.

Comment: Please note, that SO is not a code dispenser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use existing open source applications.

I think busyBox contains a such behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The system() method is for running console commands in C/C++ :

```
system(name of the command);
```